# SQL Server 2008 R2:

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, sql-server-2008-r2, report

I need to show some reports to my manager in 3 days time, but am not able to.

Every time I try to deploy reports in SSRS, I am unable to, as I am getting the following error:

> the permission granted to the user /report is not sufficient for performing this operation

I have found several solutions online, however the steps mentioned are not helping me.

Please find the screen shot below, from after trying to resolve with many approaches.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? It looks like the user trying to access does not have the required permissions. Permissions are set in the Report Server administration - the URL should be something like: http://machine_name/Reports/Pages/Settings.aspx?SelectedSubTabId=SecurityLinkID (Site settings - Security - add A/D user or group)

Comment: If you are using visual studio to deploy the reports then open visual studio as administrator and try to deploy it.

Comment: Tried the suggested option, not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

This can only be fixed with permission sets. Your user probably doesn't have the publish permission. Once you get the publish permission you can create and put reports on the website.

Steps:

First: 
   You need to navigate to the Reporting Server and click on the arrow to the right
   of the folder you need access to when you hover your mouse over it.
Second: 
   Click on security
Third: 
   At the top click on new role assignment
Fourth: 
   Enter you user name or group in the box labeled "Group or user name:" be sure to
   include your domain with it as well 
Fifth:
   Check Publisher, Browser, Reader, and Report Builder
Sixth:
   Click Ok

After this you should be set to make and publish reports.

Comment: Thank you, can u share the steps to do that .. i will be very thank full :-)

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar Venkatswamy I have updated the answer per your request. Please note you may have to have whoever manages the report server set you up if you can change security yourself.